# SQL Server: Date-time millisec AM/PM casting

Tags: sql-server, date

What'd be the best way to cast this varchar to datetime:

```
'21-DEC-17 11.09.52.020000 AM'
```

I had a look at the [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) page but none appears to match. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually your 2 `.`'s where you should have `:`'s. **Assuming** the position doesn't change, then you have a whole range of choices:

```
WITH N AS
    (SELECT N
     FROM (VALUES (NULL),
                  (NULL),
                  (NULL),
                  (NULL),
                  (NULL),
                  (NULL),
                  (NULL),
                  (NULL),
                  (NULL),
                  (NULL)) N (N) ),
Tally AS
    (SELECT TOP 200
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
     FROM N N1,
          N N2,
          N N3)
SELECT S.YourDate,
       TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(7), S.YourDate, I) AS ConvertedDate,
       I AS StyleCode
FROM Tally
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('21-DEC-17 11.09.52.020000 AM')) V(YourDate)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (STUFF(STUFF(V.YourDate, 13, 1, ':'), 16, 1, ':'))) S(YourDate)
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(7), S.YourDate, I) IS NOT NULL;
```

Edit: in fact, if you change those 2 `.`'s, you don't even need a style code, at least on my instance and language; but I assume with a value like `DEC` you are using a English derivative:

```
SELECT S.YourDate,
       TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(7), S.YourDate) AS ConvertedDate
FROM (VALUES ('21-DEC-17 11.09.52.020000 AM')) V (YourDate)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (STUFF(STUFF(V.YourDate, 13, 1, ':'), 16, 1, ':'))) S (YourDate);
```

Comment: I was trying to find an elegant way to just change the first two `.`s to `:`s. @Larnu nailed it with the `CROSS APPLY`. +1 (and a note to myself to get better with `CROSS APPLY`).

Comment: @EricBrandt it's the `STUFF` that really does the work. The `CROSS APPLY`, just means you don't have to repeat the expressions all over the place; making it more succinct (and easier to understand in my view).

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you. I had the nested `STUFF` working fine, but didn't want to repeat it all over the place because it was hard to understand (or explain). :)

Answer (score 1):

To make it convertible to a `DATETIME`:

- dots replaced with colon
- 0000 removed

SQL

```
-- results to: 2017-12-21 11:09:52.003
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('21-DEC-17 11.09.52.020000 AM', '.', ':'), '0000', '') AS DATETIME);
```

In case if `DATETIME` type is not precise enough, consider using a `DATETIME2` approach, posted in another answer

Comment: This *could* be a bad choice if the OP's data is accurate to more than 1/300 of a second; which their data does imply.

Comment: @Larnu, true, this is a drawback, worth to mention as a note